# What's the best classification model for dlib face descriptors?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want a classification model that transforms `dlib`'s face descriptors (128D vectors) to the name of the person.

The problem here is that I have a very tiny data set. I have only one image per employee and there are only less than 100 employees in total. The methods I have tried for classification include 1.calculating the euclidean distance directly, and using 2.`LinearSVC`, 3.`SVC`, and 4.`KNeighborsClassifier` in `Scikit-Learn`. So far the best result appears to lie in either `LinearSVC` or `KNeighborsClassifier`. Also, I'm working with Asian faces, so the distance between vectors of different faces is not as big (The default tolerance for the distance between the same faces is 0.6, which in my case would classify everyone as the same person. A tolerance of 0.4 would significantly reduce the occurrence of false positives but does not guarantee to recognize that person). Are there any suggestions about which model is suitable in this case? Is there a wildcard solution using `tensorflow` (with `keras`)? Thanks in advance!